# How to fix BeautifulSoup/selenium working on same website for some pages but not all?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape each page of: https://www.prosportstransactions.com/football/Search/SearchResults.php?Player=&Team=&BeginDate=&EndDate=&PlayerMovementChkBx=yes&submit=Search&start=0

Right now I have code that changes the URL iteratively. The URL is then passed into a selenium driver to grab the HTML content. The content is then put into BeautifulSoup to process. My problem is I get the following message randomly(Happens randomly on different pages which causes the program to crash. There's no consistent page that it fails on):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 89, in <module>
   i, i + 5000)
  File "scrape.py", line 37, in scrapeWebsite
    extractedInfo = info.findAll("td")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

The i, i + 5000 is used to loop to update the pages iteratively so that's not important.

Here's the code that's doing the HTML grabbing:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/Downloads/chromedriver')
print(start, stop)


madeDict = {"Date": [], "Team": [], "Name": [], "Relinquished": [], "Notes": []}

#for i in range(0, 214025, 25):
for i in range(start, stop, 25):
    print("Current Page: " + str(i))
    currUrl = url + str(i)
    driver.get(currUrl)
    driver.implicitly_wait(100
    soupPage = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    #page = urllib2.urlopen(currUrl)
    #soupPage = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    # #Sleep the program to ensure page is fully loaded
    # time.sleep(1)

    info = soupPage.find("table", attrs={'class': 'datatable center'})
    extractedInfo = info.findAll("td")
```

My guess is the page doesn't finish loading so when it tries to grab the content, the tags may not be there. However, I thought Selenium prevented that issue with dynamic loading webpages to ensure the page is fully loaded before BeautifulSoup grabs the info. I was looking at other posts and some said I needed to wait the program for the page to dynamically load but I tried that and still the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Executed without selenium, used requests instead.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://www.prosportstransactions.com/football/Search/SearchResults.php?Player=&Team=&BeginDate=&EndDate=&PlayerMovementChkBx=yes&submit=Search&start='

for i in range(0, 214025, 25):
    print("Current Page: " + str(i))
    r=requests.get(url + str(i))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    info = soup.find("table", attrs={'class': 'datatable center'})
    extractedInfo = info.findAll("td")
    print(extractedInfo)
```